# Give active class to current page on a while loop WP query for custom post types listing

Tags: custom-post-types, single

I have a single-programs.php page and at the top of this single page I need to list all the entries from the custom post type "programs". Is there a way to give "active" class to this list for the current page (current single post type" ?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
        $args = array(
            'numberposts'   => -1,
            'post_type'     => 'programs',
            'order'         => 'ASC'
        );

        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

        ?>
        <?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>
        <ul>
            <?php while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
                <li>
                    <span class="background"></span>
                    <h3 class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"></a>
                </li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </ul>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post(). ?>
```

This code is generating a list with my 4 items related to "programs", however I need to include a class "active" to the current single page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to add the class to the `li` element.

```
<li<?php echo get_queried_object_id() == get_the_ID() ? ' class="active"' : '';?>>
```

Comment: Thank you! That's the exact and simple answer I was looking for.